# Change configuration of button on windowManager TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4, file-manager

I have made a file manager for image upload on tinyMCE, and get form upload and list of image from another file (`attachment_path`). First I have successed to get image url and put to `field_name` when I select an image. But now I want change disable button (Insert) to false when select an image and put a url of image to button (use custom attribute).

script on `index_path` :

```
file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
        tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
          title: 'My File Manager',
          file: "<%= attachments_path %>",
          width: 450,
          height: 305,
          resizable : "no",
          inline : "yes",
          close_previous : "no",
          buttons: [{
              text: 'Insert',
              classes: 'widget btn primary first abs-layout-item',
              disabled: true,
              onclick: 'close',
              id: 'insertButton'
          }, {
              text: 'Close',
              onclick: 'close',
              window : win,
              input : field_name
          }]
        }, {
            oninsert: function(url) {
                win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url; 
            },
            onselect: function() {
                // 
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
```

Here's script when select an image (on `attachment_path` ):

```
$('a[data-rel="colorbox"]').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var url = $(this).find('img:first').attr('src');
     // top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams().oninsert(url);
     top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams().onselect();
});
```

I was able to find http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.WindowManager but I can't find for set configuration of buttons.

Picture for workflow

[image]

when button set to `disabled: true` :

```
<div id="insertButton" class="mce-disabled mce-widget mce-btn mce-primary mce-first mce-abs-layout-item" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="insertButton" role="button" aria-disabled="true" style="left: 319px; top: 10px; width: 56px; height: 28px;">
   <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">Insert</button>
</div>
```

when button set to `disabled: false` :

```
<div id="insertButton" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-primary mce-first mce-abs-layout-item" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="insertButton" role="button" aria-disabled="false" style="left: 319px; top: 10px; width: 56px; height: 28px;">
   <button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">Insert</button>
</div>
```

So, I try to remove class and change attribute on `onselect` function and it's works to able click insert button but when I click that, the modal not close.

```
onselect: function() {
  var adiv = $('#insertButton').closest('div');
  adiv.removeClass('mce-disabled');
  adiv.attr('aria-disabled', 'false');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Give the button some kind of a unique identifier such as Id and then enable the button from the callback.
For example, you can do:

```
file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
    tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
      title: 'My File Manager',
      file: "<%= attachments_path %>",
      width: 450,
      height: 305,
      resizable : "no",
      inline : "yes",
      close_previous : "no",
      buttons: [{
          text: 'Insert',
          classes: 'widget btn primary first abs-layout-item',
          id: 'uniqueid',
          disabled: true,
          onclick: 'close'
      }, {
          text: 'Close',
          onclick: 'close',
          window : win,
          input : field_name
      }]
    }, {
        oninsert: function(url) {
            win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url; 
        },
        onselect: function() {
            // 
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

then in the callback do this:

```
$('a[data-rel="colorbox"]').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#uniqueid').removeAttr('disabled');
     var url = $(this).find('img:first').attr('src');
     // top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams().oninsert(url);
     top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams().onselect();
});
```

Comment: I couldn't find the buttons configuration on tinyMCE site. If the id doesnt work, just give the button a unique classname and work with that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually I have tried that before make question and the modal not close when I click the button (insert button).

Comment: were you able to get the insert button enabled in the `click` function?

Comment: first, when I set `disabled: true` for insert button, the button works for close the modal, and when I set `disabled: false` and try to enable insert button using `onselect` function, insert button can able to click, but the modal not close. So I think I should to change configuration of button `disabled: true` to `disabled: false` but I can't find method for that.

Comment: Thank you!  Just to note in `v4.8` if you assign the button an id of `uniqueid`, the button itself will have an id of `uniqueid-button`, and the wrapping div will have an id of `uniqueid`.  Neither the button itself or the wrapping div have a `disabled` prop, but the wrapping div has a class `mce-disabled` which greys the button.  Remove this and the button becomes 'active' again. However; as @itx mentioned, the button still isn't really enabled, and any onclick handlers defined on the button won't fire. You'll have to close the dialog manually via your listener.  The docs are severely lacking

Answer (score 1):

You can access the buttons at the bottom of the dialog with `win.statusbar`. It's got an `items()` method which returns a `tinymce.ui.Collection`.

To enable and disable the first button ("Insert" in your case), you could use

```
// Enable the button
win.statusbar.items().eq(0).disabled(false);
// Disable the button
win.statusbar.items().eq(0).disabled(true);
```

For the second button, replace `0` with `1`, and so on.

This is, as far as I can tell, completely undocumented. I had to read the code in one of the included plugins to work out how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get another way, I do not use the button (content) from TinyMCE but make the "insert button" in `attachment_path` and make some js for selected image, put url image to button, and click event on insert button.

Scenario :

1. First image selected, prop disabled attribute on button and put url an image to button
2. And then click the button, put attribute data-url to `field_name` and close `windowManager`

button :

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary no-radius" type="button" id="iButton" data-rel="tooltip" placeholder="You need to select an image" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-url="" disabled>
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
        Insert
</button>
```

javascript :

```
$('#iButton').on('click', function(){
    if (($('#list-all-image li').hasClass('active')) && ($(this).attr('data-url') != "")){
        var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
        top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams().oninsert(url);
        top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
    } else {
        alert('Please select an image first!');
    }
});
```